# Populate a NSstring from an array

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have this structure:

Items.h:

```
@interface Items : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *tipTextField;
```

MainTableViewController.m

```
#import "Items.h"

{
NSArray *categoryArray;
NSArray *tipsArray; }

// Initialize the category array
Items *category1 = [Items new];
category1.categoryName = @"Category1";
category1.categoryImage = @"image.png";
category1.tipTextField = tipsArray [0];

Items *tip1 = [Items new];
tip1.tipTextField = @"Hello world!";

//Create tips array
tipsArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: tip1, tip2, ... nil];
```

but if I want to display, in a CategoryDetailViewController, the field "tipTextField" I receive a blank screen.

In other words, I want that "category1.tipTextField" shows text stored in "tip1.tipTextField = @"Hello world!";" but I receive a blank text field.

Any help? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT 1**: thanks to both but after changing arrays order, my app crashes in super viewDidLoad:

CategoryDetailsViewController.h

```
#import "Items.h"
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *tipTextField;
@property (nonatomic, strong) Items *item;
```

CategoryDetailsViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

self.tipTextField.text = self.item.tipTextField;
}
```

**EDIT 2:** crash is due to [NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:]:

Comment: you put tipsArray [0] in category1.tipTextField before doing this tip1.tipTextField = @"Hello world!";?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- When you are initialising the value

> category1.tipTextField = tipsArray [0];

The tipsArray = nill,i.e category1.tipTextField = nil.

- So if you want to show the value then write you code something like this

> ```
>     Items *tip1 = [Items new];
>
>     tip1.tipTextField = @"Hello world!";
>
>     //Create tips array
>    tipsArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: tip1, tip2, ... nil]; 
>
>     Items *category1 = [Items new];
>
>     category1.categoryName = @"Category1";
>
>     category1.categoryImage = @"image.png";
>
>     category1.tipTextField = tipsArray [0];
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The order matters!

You are setting `category1.tipTextField = tipsArray [0];`. `tipsArray` is nil at this point.

THEN you are adding values to the `tipsArray`. This will not affect `category1.tipTextField`'s value.

Answer (score 0):

Or use lazy instantiation anywhere in your code by overriding the getter.

```
(NSArray *)tipsArray
{
  if(_tipsArray)
  {
    _tipsArray = [NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:tip1, tip2, ... nil];
  }

return _tipsArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Create tips array
tipsArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: tip1, tip2, ... nil];
```

should come before,

```
category1.tipTextField = tipsArray [0];
```